# i always get same (last added) value, trying to get kivy's button's text, using python 3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, button, kivy

i have a python3 script, and in a Kivy app i populate a Boxlayout with some Buttons, using a for loop to set Buttons texts from a list.
i would like to get the right Button's text clicking each Button, but i always get same one. the last one.
My little code:

```
dishes=['spaghetti','rice','fish','salad']
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box=BoxLayout()
        for dish in dishes:
            self.box.add_widget(Button(text=dish,on_press=lambda *args:print(dish)))
        return self.box
app().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you definied anonymous functions with same body `print(dish)` for every button. Function is evauated on every click. So all buttons will execute `print(dish)` where `dish` is variable. Whatever you assign to this variable all buttons will print this value. In your case last value assigned to variable `dish` is `'salad'`, that's why all buttons prints `'salad'`. It may look strange, but in fact variable `dish` is available also outside for loop. Python do not destroy this variable when for loop ends. It's a Python behaviour.

To get what you need I suggest replace line:

```
self.box.add_widget(Button(text=dish,on_press=lambda *args:print(dish)))
```

with

```
self.box.add_widget(Button(text=dish,on_press=lambda self:print(self.text)))
```

So every function will get `self` as function parameter (`self` = Button instance you just clicked), then you are able to print button's text attribute.